# Prevent android status bar from appearing when touching the screen

Tags: android, fullscreen, statusbar

I've set my theme to @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen, but I'm trying to prevent the status bar from appearing when touching the screen.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in your onCreate. (You may need to set this before doing setContentView.)  <s>You'll need</s>

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR">
```

in your manifest file too. (ETA: see comment below)

Comment: `android.permission.STATUS_BAR` is granted only for applications from firmware. If you try to set this permission in you AndroidManifest.xml, you retrive following warning:

03-21 17:20:26.420 W/PackageManager(  145): Not granting permission android.permission.STATUS_BAR to package com.example (protectionLevel=3 flags=0x8be46)